# Distribute evenly some formula or text randomly  on a page

Tags: formatting, positioning

Suppose you have n variations of a small text or a formula like this:

```
% Formula 1
\begin{align}
      v(t_o) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{v(t_0 + h) - v(t_0)}{h}
\end{align}

% Formula 2
\begin{align}
      v(t_o) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{v(t_0 + \Delta t) - v(t_0)}{\Delta t}
\end{align}

%...

% Formula n
%...
```

Is it possible to distribute evenly those formulas randomly, on a page with random rotations of the formulas by +- x degree. The formulas must not overlap.

Comment: You can use `tikz` for this.

Comment: @'Leo Liu'. Thanks. Could you provide some more details?

Comment: You could manually distribute them using `\hspace` and `\vspace` and take the random rotation from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9323/are-there-any-latex-easter-eggs/9331#9331

Comment: I'm a little confused by 'distribute evenly those formulas randomly'. Do you want the distribution even (on a rectangular or circular grid for example) and the formulas randomly assigned to the points, or would you like the distribution random (not on a grid)?

Answer (score 4):

Following @Leo's suggestion, here's a start for how you might do this in Tikz:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{/rotatednodes/.cd, width/.initial=10cm, 
  height/.initial=10cm, maxrotation/.initial=20}
\newcount\@nodenum

\newcommand{\rotatednodes}[2][]{%
\pgfkeys{/rotatednodes/.cd, #1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\pgfkeysvalueof{/rotatednodes/width}, 
                    y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/rotatednodes/height}]
\@nodenum=0
\def\@eqlist{#2}
\foreach\eq in \@eqlist{
  \advance\@nodenum by 1
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\x}{0}{100}
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\y}{0}{100}
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\r}{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/rotatednodes/maxrotation}}%
    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/rotatednodes/maxrotation}}
 \node[rotate=\r] (randomnode_\number\@nodenum) at (\x/100,\y/100) {\eq};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatother
```

which you would then use like

```
\rotatednodes[width=2cm, maxrotation=90]{$x$, $y$, $z$, $a$, $b$, $c$}
```

which gives

[image: Equations positioned and rotated at random]

or something similar to it.

The optional arguments are `width`, `height`, and `maxrotation` which all do more or less what they say. The fiddling with keys for the arguments was just for fun: the crucial bit is using `\pgfmathrandominteger` to randomise the position and rotation of the nodes, and I guess using `\foreach` to loop through the various equations.

There are several issues with this simple implementation, notably that absolutely no attempt is made to check for node overlap, and that only the centres of the nodes are guaranteed to fall within a `width`x`height` rectangle, but hopefully this will help you find a solution that works for your particular case.

Comment: You can use `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist` and `\pgfmathrandomitem` to get random item from equations.