# Randomizing font selection in XeLaTeX, per character

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The effect of the anonymous letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38599/the-effect-of-the-anonymous-letter)

I have a bit of a programming question, and I think it's in line with what LaTeX (XeLaTeX in my case) is suited to do.

I would like to randomly use a font (from a list of fonts) for each glyph being typeset. I wanted to do this for a project in the style of a "ransom letter" - imagine individual characters being clipped from a different source.

I wanted to use a set of fonts that were modelled after typewriters, all opentype fonts. How would I approach this?

Ideally I would type the text normally, and have TeX do the heavy-lifting of randomly picking a character-set for each glyph.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [The effect of the anonymous letter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38599/5764). Please let us know whether the linked post solves your problem.

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate. If it would be really different to the linked question, please edit and explain, we could reopen it if meaningful.