# How to apply Bionic-Reading style to the whole document?

Tags: environments

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645018/154536), a user showed how to apply the [Bionic-Reading](https://bionic-reading.com/) style to specific paragraphs of a TeX document.

The answer suggested defining a macro to achieve the desired effect, as requested in the question.

`\bionic{Confucius said: Madam, I'm Adam.}`

produces the output

> **Conf**ucius **sa**id: **Ma**dam, I'm **Ad**am.

Now, I have a very big TeX file with a lot of text and equations and I want to implement this style throughout the document. Ideally, I would like to enclose the entire text between a command like

`\bionic . . . \endbionic` like the solution suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597683/how-to-globally-apply-all-texts-as-the-argument-of-a-command). How should I go about this?

Answer (score 4):

It should be implemented but with limitations:

- The contents of `\bionic...\endbionic` must be plain text without any used macros. Only text of paragraphs separated by empty lines. I implement single exception (as an example): inline math mode `$...$` can be used but it must be preceded by space.
- The hyphenation cannot work.

The `\bionic...\endbionic` can encapsulated several paragraphs or (on the other hand) it can be used inside the paragraph in order to modify only a part of the paragraph.

The bionic percent parameter can be set by `\setbionic{num}`, default is `\setbionic{50}`.

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\setbionic#1{\def\wratio{#1}}
\setbionic{50}

\long\def\bionic #1\endbionic{%
   \begingroup
   \let\bionicfin=\par 
   \everypar{\bionicS\bionicA}%
   \ifhmode \def\bionicfin{}\bionicS \expandafter \bionicA\fi
   #1 \bionicfin
   \endgroup
}
\long\def\bionicA #1{%
   \let\next=\bionicC
   \ifx#1\par \let\next=\relax \fi
   \ifx#1\bionicfin \let\next=\relax \fi
   \ifx#1$\let\next=\bionicM \fi %$
   \next #1%
}
\def\bionicC #1 {\ifx\par#1\else
    \spacebetweenwords
    \tmpnum=0 \lcount #1{}% saves the number of letters to \tmpnum
    \multiply\tmpnum by\wratio \divide\tmpnum by100
    \testIm #1''\end % says \tmpnum=0 if #1 includes ' inside the word
    \bgroup \bf \wordpart #1%
    \expandafter\bionicA \fi
}
\def\bionicM $#1${ $#1$\bionicS\futurelet\next\bionicN}
\def\bionicN{\expandafter\ifx\space\next 
   \afterfi{ \afterassignment\bionicA\let\next= }\else \afterfi\bionicA\fi
}
\def\bionicS{\def\spacebetweenwords{\def\spacebetweenwords{ }}}

\def\lcount #1{\ifx^#1^\else \advance\tmpnum by1 \expandafter\lcount\fi}
\def\wordpart #1{%
   \ifnum\tmpnum=0 \egroup#1% 
   \else #1\advance\tmpnum by-1 \expandafter \wordpart \fi}
\def\testIm #1'#2'#3\end{\ifx^#2^\else \tmpnum=0 \fi}
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}

Text \bionic inside the paragraph.\endbionic{} Next verse. 

\bionic 
Confucius said: Madam, I'm Adam.

Next paragraph $a + b = c$ uff.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.

Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.
\endbionic

\bye
```

You can try this example by Plain TeX, i.e. `pdftex document`.